# como conseguir index position de cluster marker en onClusterItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps, cluster

estoy desarrollando una app con google maps, mis markers (sus LatLng y mas info) los obtengo de una API, y estos estan colocados en el mapa con clustering.

Ahora cada vez que hago click en uno de estos markers, yo quisiera conseguir su index position para asi luego conseguir toda la informacion que viene con ellos.

Como puedo lograr esto? con el siguiente codigo:

```
   it.forEach { latLonModel ->
            

            clusterManager!!.setOnClusterItemClickListener(object : ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem?> {
                override fun onClusterItemClick(item: MyItem?): Boolean {
                    clickedClusterItem = item!!



                    return false
                }
            })




            addPersonItems(latLonModel)
            clusterManager!!.markerCollection.setInfoWindowAdapter(MyCustomAdapterForItems(this))
            clusterManager!!.cluster()
```

estoy un poco perdido, ya que lo obtengo dentro de onClusterItemClick(item: MyItem?)..es un objeto item, y no un marker, con el cual luego podria conseguir data como id.. y position eventualmente.

Alguien menciono en algun post manipular onClusterItemRendered en mi CustomClusterRenderer de la suguiente manera:

```
override fun onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem: MyItem, marker: Marker) {
    super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker)
    var markers = Hashtable<String, LatLng>()
    markers.put(marker.id,clusterItem.position)
}
```

pero no logro comprenderlo, ni mucho menos aplicarlo...como y en donde?

alguna idea como lograr esto? es mi primera vez trabajando con clustering, cualquier ayuda es muy bienvenida, ya que estoy hace dos dias atascado con este problema.
Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

A ver si alguien te puede dar una respuesta mejor, pero creo que no es necesario que uses el listener setOnClusterItemClickListener.  El cluster extiende de marker, por lo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager.markerManager)
2. googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
3. Cuando tengas las posiciones, las añades al cluster:  clusterManager.addItem(tuItem).  El item es una clase que extiende de ClusterItem, pasa por constructor el LatLng y la info que necesites.

Prueba lo anterior, así lo hice hace un mes para pintar una polyline con cluster y bien.

Comment: muchisimas gracias Manuel, realmente necesito ayuda! ..ahora mismo voy a intentar tu consejo, luego te comento al respecto

Comment: Manuel, o alguien mas?podrian mostrarme alguna referencia de codigo porque no logro comprenderlo bien... ya tengo googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager.markerManager)
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager),

luego como consigo esas positions?  ..perdon pero estoy ya muy mareado

Comment: normalmente, colocaria un tag en cada marker, y luego podria obtener los tags con setOnMarkerClickListener ..y asi las posiciones...  pero no comprendo como usar todo esto de esta manera...

Comment: vale, acabo de revisar código y abría que crear una variable que contenga la lista de markers.  Esta variable debe ser del tipo MarkerManager.Collection, por ejemplo MarkerManager.Collection markers.  Tiene un listener propio   startEndMarkersCollection.setOnMarkerClickListener {} y por último faltaría añadir el marker a la lista: markers.addMarker(markerOptions)

Comment: Sos muy buena gente, agradezco que este invirtiendo tu tiempo aun, me siento muy perdido con esto, ahora si, el problema es que ..la lista de Markers...son coordenadas LatLng que obtengo de una API..   a traves de un ViewModel, parseo su data en el cluster... y despliega todos los clustered markers en el mapa..entonces  no me estaria funcionado el MarkerManager.Collection .. ya que esta lista es objeto de una clase diferente..no se si me comprendes?
 la lista que parseo de ViewModel es IT y pertener a una clase particular (en mi caso scooter)..luego no logro realizar MarkerManager.Collection

Comment: Cuando clickeo sobre el clustered marker puedo conseguir su LatLng position, pero en verdad es que necesito la index position...para luego realizar por ejemplo:  it.get(i).battery  de esa position especifica ..por esa razon mencionaba setOnClusterItemClickListener al principio.. porque no tenia forma de acceder a otro metodo, debido a que mis markers son LatLng dentro del cluster

Comment: Ok, ahora entiendo... entonces olvídate lo de los markers, porque en mi caso usé dos markers que son el punto inicial y final de la polyline, y los puntos intermedios son un clúster.  Entonces en tu caso todos los markers estarán en un clúster.  En este caso debes usar clusterManager.addItem(tuItem).  tuItem ees un objecto que extiende de ClusterItem y ahí le pasas por constructor los datos que necesites, no es necesario la position, directamente constructor TuITem(Scooter scooter) y dentro haces un public Scooter getScooter()

Comment: Léete la documentanción de android oficial, está bien explicado https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering?hl=es-419

Comment: justo estoy leyendo la documentacion en detalles, luego te comento si me fue bien..sos muy amable Manuel, gracias por tu tiempo!... luego te comento!

Comment: Manuel ojala aun estes despierto, sos un genio bro!! ya lo hice funcionar! me hiciste ver la logica y era mas facil de lo que pense!!! GRACIAS!!! te doy thumbs up en tu respuuesta aunque no es la repuesta final!! gracias!!